# Installing a language pack using powershell invoking dism.exe command online

Tags: powershell, dism

```
**$exefile = "C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe"
$command="C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe /online /add-package /package-path:"+"C:\lang\fr-ca\lp.cab"

Invoke-Expression $command**
```

I am getting below error and language pack is not getting installed by using above command

Image Version: 10.0.10116.0

**Error: 87**

> The package-path option is not recognized in this context. For more
>   information, refer to the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825265.aspx). The parameter name is `/PackagePath` (without hyphen), not `/Package-Path`.

Comment: But after Installing using same command like below code,                                {PS C:\Windows\system32> $exefile = "C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe"
$command="C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:"+"C:\lang\fi-fi\lp.cab"
Invoke-Expression $command }  not getting any error but language pack is not getting reflected in Region and language setting